# Is NSApp terminate:id deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsapplication

I have been searching for how to terminate my application programmatically. I found in many topics people using `NSApp terminate:id`.

In Xcode `terminate:id` is crossed. Is this method deprecated ? Should I use it to terminate my application ? If no which is the right way to do it ?

**Update:**
Picture of what i mean when I say that it's crossed: 
[image]

Comment: I just call `exit()` function [(doc)](http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-exit)

Comment: @progrmr, in a Cocoa app, you should call `-terminate:`. It's important for things that observe the `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification`, which might include stuff within the frameworks. One example of termination-time work is resolving data that's been promised to the pasteboard.

Comment: @Ken: good to know, thanks!  [Terminate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate:) it is then.  I'm used to iOS where terminate is not allowed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell my Cocoa application to quit from within the application itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659177/how-can-i-tell-my-cocoa-application-to-quit-from-within-the-application-itself)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't see that `terminate` is deprecated. A possible cause for the compiler warning might be that in

```
[NSApp terminate:sender]
```

`NSApp` returns a general `id`, so that the compiler does not know which `terminate` message is actually meant. An indeed, if I use "Jump to Definition", Xcode jumps to

```
@protocol NSInputServiceProvider
...
- (void) terminate:(id)sender NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(10_0, 10_6);
```

But if you use the equivalent code

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:sender];
```

then the compiler warning goes away.

Answer (score 1):

[Nope, not deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-CACCGIJC):

---

### terminate:

Terminates the receiver.

```
- (void)terminate:(id)sender
```

#### Parameters

*sender*

Typically, this parameter contains the object that initiated the termination request.

#### Discussion

This method is typically invoked when the user chooses Quit or Exit from the application’s menu.

When invoked, this method performs several steps to process the termination request. First, it asks the application’s document controller (if one exists) to save any unsaved changes in its documents. During this process, the document controller can cancel termination in response to input from the user. If the document controller does not cancel the operation, this method then calls the delegate’s `applicationShouldTerminate:` method. If `applicationShouldTerminate:` returns `NSTerminateCancel`, the termination process is aborted and control is handed back to the main event loop. If the method returns `NSTerminateLater`, the application runs its run loop in the `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode` mode until the `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:` method is called with the value `YES` or `NO`. If the `applicationShouldTerminate:` method returns `NSTerminateNow`, this method posts a `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification` notification to the default notification center.

Do not bother to put final cleanup code in your application’s `main()` function—it will never be executed. If cleanup is necessary, perform that cleanup in the delegate’s `applicationWillTerminate:` method.

#### Availability

Available in OS X v10.0 and later.

#### See Also

- `– run`
- `– stop:`
- `– applicationShouldTerminate:` (NSApplicationDelegate)
- `– applicationWillTerminate:` (NSApplicationDelegate)
- `– replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:`
- `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification`

#### Related Sample Code

- BlastApp
- PreLoginAgents

#### Declared In

NSApplication.h